# JNI error while building

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native

I'm following "https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html" Netbeans tutorial for JNI but when I build the project I get this error in the Netbeans output:

```
cd 'E:\Janhavi\Projects\JNIDemoCdl'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/e/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 356ms)
cd 'E:\Janhavi\Projects\JNIDemoCdl'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/4d151f2
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/4d151f2/JNIDemo.o.d"
gcc -shared -m64   -c -g -I/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include -I/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include/win32 -include /cygdrive/C/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include -include /cygdrive/C/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/4d151f2/JNIDemo.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/4d151f2/JNIDemo.o /cygdrive/E/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl/JNIDemo.c
cc1: fatal error: /cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/4d151f2/JNIDemo.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/e/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/e/Janhavi/Projects/JNIDemoCdl'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 557ms)
```

This is my first attempt with JNI and I am kind of stuck at this point.
Please let me know what's the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you gave the path 
'/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include' of C drive accessed from cygwin. Any specific reason for this?

Comment: Cygdrive is getting captured in console whereas I have kept all files in the C drive and there is not a single folder name cygdrive. Not understanding where that cygdrive is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JNIDemoCdl` is calling make inside cygwin64. This is the reason you get `/cygdrive` before each directory name as they are being executed inside cygwin mounted drives.

I think the issue is with the space in '**Program Files**' which you end up getting:

> cc1: fatal error: /cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/include:
>   No such file or directory compilation terminated.

Try storing `/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/` under a directory with no space in the name and build the project again.